# Which object is the default organization timezone stored on?

Tags: timezone, org-wide-defaults

I've got a managed package and I'm trying to programmatically figure out what the default timezone is for the orgs that my package is installed on. I've found where to set the default timezone in the interface (setup -> company profile -> company information), but the default timezone doesn't appear to be available on the Organization object which is where I'd expected it to be.

Anyone know on what object the default timezone for an org is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Organization` object's `TimeZoneSidKey` holds the org time zone setting:

```
Organization org = [SELECT TimeZoneSidKey FROM Organization LIMIT 1];

System.debug(org.TimeZoneSidKey);
```

Comment: Glad they finally got around to adding that at some point. I've been out of Salesforce for a while now though, so too late for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

I just found https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bEGWAA2

Which indicates that the default time zone is not available programatically. :-(

Please tell me this isn't the answer. I'll leave this question unanswered for a bit to see if anyone else knows better.